# Unable to rebase repository

Tags: git

Origin repo is used only by me, but at some point some point starting from 1_1_82 tag some unwanted branch has been created(some bug in build/commit script). Then my development line continued as normal from 1_1_84. Now what I want is the last tag to be the remote master. At the moment if I clone it, 1_1_83 is set as default working version, not sure why, HEAD is pointing to 1_1_142. Anyway, I tried to do

```
git push origin master
```

and got

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
```

Then I tried to do rebase, but faced some conflicts on branch 1_1_82 and 83, which is tedious work to resolve.

So the question is, how to make my origin/master point to 1_1_42 tag?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  Please update your question showing branch diagrams for what is going on.  If you can't do this, then you should not expect someone else to understand either.

Comment: I thought branch diagram is depicted in my post. What I want is origin/master to point to remote HEAD. Right now origin/master is pointing to some old branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put `master` next to the `debian_version_1_1_142`, just do:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard debian_version_1_1_142
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

Please, be aware :

- that the `--hard` flag will lost all the uncommited changes (stash them if you have i...)
- that the `--force-with-lease` flag will prevent the error you get but in some cases (not here because that's what you want) destroy some history in the remote.

Comment: I would like `origin/master` as well next to `debian_version_1_1_142`

Comment: This seems to agree with what the OP literally said, at least +1

Comment: @Pablo the ref is automatically updated when the 'push' is done.

Comment: Just one last thing, how was better to describe my problem in my original post and in simple words how did solution work?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "how to make my origin/master point to 1_1_42 tag"? The response is

just tag master with 1_1_42 and `git push origin 1_1_42`.

If you have rebased something, ... you have overwritten the history. This means you need to force the update of master (pay attention, because you can lost some pieces of the git history). Just `git push origin master -f`.

---

edit:

In your local computer just

- git push origin :master
- git checkout debian_version_1_1_142
- git branch -D master
- git branch master
- git push origin master

Comment: This gives me `Everything up-to-date`. But still origin/master is pointing to 1_1_83. I haven't rebased something so far, haven't succeeded.

Comment: `git push origin :master` gives `remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master`. Also the last push failed: `! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)`.

Comment: Change the default branch on github.